# SQL Server Express works but SQL Server doesn't

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, metadata

I have mvc application (tutorial) running OK on SQL Server Express:

```
<add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial       
 Catalog=MusicStore;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

but giving error when using another installed instance of SQL:

```
<add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="data source=.\SQLSERVER;Initial   
Catalog=MusicStore;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Connection to sql works fine, but I don't know how to fix this :

> ERROR:
>   Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been added to the DbModelBuilder conventions.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been added to the DbModelBuilder conventions.
>
> Source Error:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using EF. try to add this in your dbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
}
```

OR
drop the database and let EF recreate it itself